# Numerically Solve a Second Order ODE with singular coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to solve the following *numerically*:

$$xy''+y'+xy=x$$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$. I need the solution for $x:[0, 10]$.

I've written the ode as a system of first order odes like so:

**function dydx = final2( x,y )

dydx = [y(2); 1 - 1/x*y(2)-y(1)];

end**

I can't use ode45 since the singular point happens at 0. I get a nice solution when solve it symbolically, but I am being required to solve it numerically.

I've also perturbed from 0 initially and gotten a good solution, but I need to make it work at 0.

I've read through and tried several of the built in functions in Matlab but cannot get any to work. Can someone point me to the solver that could work?

Comment: I've never done numerical solutions to singular ode's. But looking at your equation, you get $xy''\rightarrow -1$ as $x\rightarrow0$. I would love to know how to deal with that numerically!

Comment: There are no solution that satisfy both of the initial conditions. The general solution to the ODE is $y(x) = 1 + aJ_0(x) + bY_0(x)$ where $J,Y$ are Bessel-functions. Imposing $y(0) = 0$ we get $a=1$ and $b=0$ for which $y'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Correction: it should be $a=-1$ in the comment above.

Comment: So there's definitely a problem with the IC's, right?

Comment: Yes this is true for the exact solution, but can the problem be done numerically without fooling with the ICs?

Comment: No. Since the solution do not exist, any numerical results you might obtain will have no meaning (and it will not work anyway as $y''(0)$ will have to be $\infty$).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need initial conditions. Since you have the analytical solution, use it to make sure you have valid initial conditions first. I did some searching and the "backwards Euler" method may be useful.

Comment: btw for reference: see [this page](http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/08/08/solving-bessels-equation-numerically/) for tips on how to solve this ODE in Matlab.

Comment: Could I set option on a mass matrix so that I don't have problems with the singularity?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Using ode15s, you can set up a mass matrix which feeds the singularity into the ode solver.

dydt = [y(2), x - y(2) -x*(y1)] is the function handle.

M = [1 0;0 x] is the mass matrix.

Using odeset and setting the mass matrix to M and then providing 'MassSingular' option 'yes' and MStateDependence' to 'none' gets the job done!